Old math books fonts
I am currently working on a book/articles. I really (really!) enjoy the styling of the Nagoya Math Journal from the late 80s-90s. Here's an example : https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/6E62D7837868BA9A7A0E389C0591E8C4/S0027763000001653a.pdf/algebraic-k3-surfaces-with-finite-automorphism-groups.pdf. The layout is clean and "airy", I find the general and math fonts used just to be perfect ...!
Could a gentle soul help me replicate the first page(s) of this article ? At least could someone indicate me the fonts used ?
Thank you for your time !

A very tidy presentation.  I still find the presence of full caps in math in small caps running heads a bit disconcerting.

@barbarabeeton well given that it took you 40 years to find the shift key it's not surprising you get unsettled by capital letters

The font in the title is different, but you can reproduce the article quite faithfully with fouriernc.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth=305pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[tiny]{titlesec}

\DeclareMathSizes{10}{10}{5}{4}
\linespread{1.1}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{rsfs}{\skewchar\font127 }
\DeclareFontShape{U}{rsfs}{m}{n}{%
  <-6> rsfs5
  <6-8>> rsfs7
  <8-> rsfs10
}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\bfseries\mathversion{bold}
ALGEBRAIC $K3$ SURFACES \\
WITH FINITE AUTOMORPHISM GROUPS
\end{center}
\begin{center}
SHIGEYUKI KONDŌ
\end{center}

\section*{Introduction}

The purpose of this paper is to give a proof to the result announced in~[3]. 
Let $X$ be an algebraic surface defined over $\bm{C}$. $X$ is called a $K3$ 
\emph{surface} if its canonical line bundle $K_X$ is trivial and 
$\dim H^1(X, \mathscr{O}_X) = 0$. It is known that the automorphism group 
$\operatorname{Aut}(X)$ of $X$ is isomorphic, up to a finite group, to the 
factor group $O(S_X)/W_X$, where $O(S_X)$ is the automorphism group of the 
Picard lattice of $X$ (i.e.\ $S_X$ is the Picard group of $X$ together with 
the intersection form) and $W_X$ is its subgroup generated by all reflections 
associated with elements with square $(-2)$ of $S_X$~([11]). Recently 
Nikulin~[8],~[10] has completely classified the Picard lattices of algebraic 
$K3$ surfaces with finite automorphism groups.

\end{document}


The original


The text font looks like Century Schoolbook (the main title font is different, see the W letter).
A good clone is TeX Gyre Schola.
Apart from the font, have you tried to approximate the style that you like? If you have specific issues that you cannot solve, the community here will help (probably better to ask individual questions).

Classic Math, Computer Science textbooks and published papers often used TeX (or LaTeX) as the layout language/typesetting.
TeX used Computer Modern as its default font. It is often called "CMU Serif" and can be found online in a lot of font repositories.
The original font can also be found at: 
https://cm-unicode.sourceforge.io/download.html

The OP wasn't asking for Computer Modern or clones thereof.

Hmm, then why did they ask: "At least could someone indicate me the fonts used?"

The OP is pointing to an article and would like to know the font used therein.
